# FIR filter low-pass window

Tags: c++, filter, wav

I'm trying to implement a FIR filter low-pass windowed, but the result is not consistent.

Here is my code:

```
#define N_FIR 51
main() {
    FILE* fin;  
    FILE* fout = NULL;  
    short *data16bits = NULL;

    fin = fopen("file3.wav", "rb");
    fread(&wavHeader, sizeof(wav_hdr), 1, fin);

    data16bits = (short*)malloc(wavHeader.subChunk2Size * sizeof(short));   
    fread(data16bits, wavHeader.bitsPerSample, wavHeader.subChunk2Size / 2, fin); 
    fclose(fin);   

    fout = fopen("FIRfilterLowPass.wav", "wb");
    fwrite(&wavHeader, sizeof(wav_hdr), 1, fout);

    double *fltr = (double *)malloc(N_FIR * sizeof(double));
    FIRfilterLowPass(1000, wavHeader.sampleRate, fltr);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < wavHeader.subChunk2Size; i++) {
        double result = 0;   
        short result_short = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N_FIR && (i - j) >= 0; j++) {
            result += fltr[j] * data16bits[i - j]; 
        }
        result_short = (short)result;   
        fwrite(&result_short, sizeof(short), 1, fout);
    }
}

void FIRfilterLowPass(double f_c, double f_samp, double* fltr) {
    f_c = f_c / f_samp;
    double w_c = 2 * PI * f_c;
    int middle = N_FIR / 2;

    for (int n = -N_FIR / 2; n <= N_FIR / 2; n++) {
        if (n == 0) {
            fltr[middle] = 2 * f_c;
        }
        else {
            fltr[middle + n] = sin(2 * PI * f_c * n) / (PI * n);
        }
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < N_FIR; n++) {
        fltr[n] = fltr[n] * (0.5f + 0.5f * cos((2 * PI * n) / N_FIR));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, because the wave looks like this:

[image]

But it should look more like this:

[image]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you want C or do you want C++?

Comment: @tadman Sorry, I put `c` by mistake in tags. `C++` is what I want

Comment: You may have to double-check your math here. Have you compared to a reference implementation, even if that's just a spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, the function `FIRfilterLowPass` is took from an online course. But I'm not very sure how to use it, inside main. Here I ask for your help :D

Comment: II've got even less of an idea than you as I don't know what values I'm supposed to be seeing for the "right" output. That's why I'm suggesting having a reference of some sort, even if it's a spreadsheet of expected values. Debugging this sort of stuff can be really time-consuming unless you approach it more systematically. Verify each step is working correctly before integrating that function into the rest of your code.